# parsing list of object in dwr

Tags: arraylist, dwr

I have a remote function testdwr, which returns a list of objects(test). How should i parse the list of objects in the handler method? Code shown below

public List testdwr(String message) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.setName("mahati");
        List arrayList = new ArrayList();
        arrayList.add(test);
        return arrayList;
    }

handler method:

function update()
{ findaccounts.testdwr("somestring : ",function(data){
alert(data); }

the alert box gives the output as "object Object"!!

Comment: Whenever you accept an answer, you can appreciate them by voting up. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ArrayList returned from the server will looks like,

```
[Object { name="Mahati"}, Object { name="meena"}, Object { name="keerthi" }.....]
```

You can have a loop like this,

```
for(var i=0; i<arrayList.length; i++)
{
    var testObj = arrayList[i];
    //Here, you can do what you want! like...
    alert(testObj.name);
    alert(testObj.age);
}
```

Like [Blake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/391026/blake) said, try to use FireBug, its an addon for firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like data[0].name

Using alert(data.length) show show 1.

Have you tried using Firebug on Firefox. It allows you to set a break point in the javascript code and examin the variables.